# Creating a hexagon class

Tags: c++, class

The exercise 8 of chapter 13 of book (http://www.stroustrup.com/programming1.html) says:

*Define a class Hexagon (a Hexagon is a regular six sided polygon). Use the center and the distance from the center to a corner point as constructor arguments.*

I solved it this way (below code). And although I had doubt about the answer but anyway then went for exercise 13-10 which says:

*Define a class regular_polygon. Use the center, the number of sides (>2) and the distance from the center to a corner as constructor arguments.*

When I thought about a solution for this one, I found that utilize a loop and finding a relationship between i & j is very difficult, more than the previous one (13-8).

First: Is this below code *what you expected* as a solution for exercise 13-8 please?

Then: Is there any way related to the answer of exercise 13-8 (below code) which is possible to be used for solving the exercise 13-10 please?

Thanks in advance.

```
   #include <Simple_window.h>

 struct Hexagon : Shape {
        Hexagon(Point p, int d): d(d)
       { add(Point(p)); }

    void draw_lines() const 
        { 
        fl_line(point(0).x-d,point(0).y,  point(0).x-d/2,point(0).y-(d-d/20*3),
                        point(0).x+d/2,point(0).y-(d-d/20*3));    
        fl_line(point(0).x+d/2,point(0).y-(d-d/20*3),  point(0).x+d,point(0).y,
                        point(0).x+d/2,point(0).y+(d-d/20*3));             
        fl_line(point(0).x+d/2,point(0).y+(d-d/20*3),  point(0).x-d/2,point(0).y+(d-d/20*3),
                        point(0).x-d,  point(0).y);  
        }
 private:
    int d;
};

 int main() {
    using namespace Graph_lib; 

     Simple_window win(Point(100,100), 600,400, "Hexagon"); 
     Graph_lib::Rectangle r(Point (50,50), 400,200);
     Point p(100,100);
      int d = 50;
      Hexagon h(p,d);
      win.attach(h);
    win.wait_for_button();
}
```

The problem is how to use of trigonometry! Anyway I thought about it and wrote this one. Although it works properly for square and I didn't use any magic number in it but for other regular polygons it doesn't work properly. May you please have a look at it?

```
#include <Simple_window.h>

struct Regular_Polygon : Shape {

    Regular_Polygon(Point p, int d, int s): d(d), s(s)
       { add(Point(p)); }

    void draw_lines() const 
    { 
         fl_line(point(0).x-d+(360/s-d),point(0).y-d+(360/s-d),   point(0).x+d-(360/s-d),point(0).y-d+(360/s-d));
         fl_line(point(0).x+d-(360/s-d),point(0).y-d+(360/s-d),   point(0).x+d-(360/s-d),point(0).y+d-(360/s-d));
             fl_line(point(0).x+d-(360/s-d),point(0).y+d-(360/s-d),   point(0).x-d+(360/s-d),point(0).y+d-(360/s-d));
         fl_line(point(0).x-d+(360/s-d),point(0).y+d-(360/s-d),   point(0).x-d+(360/s-d),point(0).y-d+(360/s-d));
    }

private:
    int d, s;
};

int main()
{
    using namespace Graph_lib; 

    Simple_window win(Point(100,100), 600,400, "Regular_Polygon");  
    Point p(200,200);
    int d = 100;
    int s = 4;
    Regular_Polygon r_p(p,d,s);
    win.attach(r_p);
    win.wait_for_button();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch of ways to improve your code:

- Use of magic numbers, like 3/20, should be avoided.
- Format your code consistently.
- I'm halfway sure that the positioning of the hexagon points is wrong, even if it looks good for certain values of the radius.
- No documentation. Calling something 'd' is not obvious.
- There's a `using` declaration in `main()`, but also a fully qualified name used there.
- If you used trigonometry to calc the positions for the corners, the method for doing that for any regular polygon would become obvious.
- Repeatedly using the same term sometimes merits factoring out that term to a constant and referring to that instead. It also makes the code clearer, like for example `Point const c = point(0);` in `draw_lines()`.

Comment: Respectively. 1-Yeah, it should be avoided but there wasn't any substitute. 3- Test it with any value for radius. Give the _d_ and number you like and look at the result. 4- d = distance. 5- I needed to declare it. 6- If I could use of trigonometry it would be very excellent and probably the problem for exercise 13-10 would be almost solved! Can you (say) change the code to be first, suitable for ex 13-8 and then, usable for ex 13-10 as well?

Comment: Concerning magic numbers, there is an alternative, just search for the term "magic number" and you will find lots of suggestions. (d-d/20*3) is d*(17/20) is 0.85*d, but it should rather be 0.87*d. Anyhow, to answer your follow-up question, yes you can write code that is usable for both exercises, since one is a generalization of the other.

Comment: Yeah, completely agree, one is the generalization of the another. But using something like _0.87*d_ doesn't seem to be possible. I think there should be one answer related to the trigonometry. The solution should be something that is related to the points on the circumference.

Comment: Think it's your exercise. What would you do this? Bear in mind that the problem is exercise 13-10!

Comment: Since the number of corners is variable, you will need a loop. In order to compute the positions of the corner, you will need sine and cosine functions.

Comment: OK, but how to use of sine and cosine functions for that which indicate the vertices of that regular polygon?

Comment: Draw a sketch and search the web. I'm not doing your homework.

Comment: Yeah. You have forgotten here is a forum. Anyway, nice time.